# Referencing forward-declared function in anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand anonymous namespaces. Right now the requirements from my code are this:

```
#file.c
namespace X
{
  void foo(){int x = bar(2);}
} //X

namespace
{
  int bar(int x);
} //namespace
```

or

```
#file.c
namespace X
{
  void foo(){int x = bar(2);}

namespace
  {
    int bar(int x);
  } // namespace
} // X
```

I've tried to forward-declare foo:

```
namespace X {
int bar(int);
...
```

But thus far that just leads to a linker error.

Answer (score 6):

The anonymous namespace is consistent within each translation unit, you can reopen it like any other namespace:

```cpp
namespace X
{
  namespace
  {
    int bar(int x);
  } // namespace

  void foo() { int x = bar(2); }

  namespace
  {
    int bar(int x) { return 2 * x; }
  } // namespace
} // X
```